# Move checkboxes on checked jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I want to move the checkboxes if they are checked.

```
<div id="chkboxes">
<input type="checkbox" name="city" id="1"/> One <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="city" id="2"/> Two <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="city" id="3"/> Three   <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="city" id="4"/> Four    <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="city" id="5"/> Five    <br />
</div>
```

So if any checkbox is checked, it should move on the top of the list. How do I do that with jquery?

I am trying to build the pseudo code, but not able to get the logic.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use jQuery's `insertBefore` method. Capture checked inputs, remove them and insert them before the first checkbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
  var list = $("ul"),
        origOrder = list.children();
    
    list.on("click", ":checkbox", function() {
        var i, checked = document.createDocumentFragment(),
            unchecked = document.createDocumentFragment();
        for (i = 0; i < origOrder.length; i++) {
            if (origOrder[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked) {
                checked.appendChild(origOrder[i]);
            } else {
                unchecked.appendChild(origOrder[i]);
            }
        }
        list.append(checked).append(unchecked);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" id="one" />One</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" id="two" />Two</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" id="three" />Three</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" id="four" />Four</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" id="five" />Five</label></li>
</ul>
```

try this with jquery and working [jsfiddle click here](http://jsfiddle.net/scSYV/139/)

Comment: Thanks .. Exactly what I am looking for .. so when the checkbox is unchecked the box is listed in its original order. cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the JavaScript function like this

```
$('table').on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function () {
 var $this = $(this);
 var row = $this.closest('tr');
 if ( $this.prop('checked') ){ // move to top
    row.insertBefore( row.parent().find('tr:first-child') )
        .find('label').html('move to bottom'); 
 }
 else { // move to bottom
    row.insertAfter( row.parent().find('tr:last-child') )
        .find('label').html('move to top');  
 }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/51rbk65t/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `onChange` handler and if the checkbox is checked then clone the checkbox and `remove` it. Now prepend the clone element to the list of checkboxes using `.prepend()`

```js
$(function(){
  var checkedbox;
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked', 'checked')){
      checkedbox = $(this).parent().clone();
    }
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $('#chkboxes').prepend(checkedbox);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chkboxes">
<div><input type="checkbox" name="city" id="1"/> One <br /></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="city" id="2"/> Two <br /></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="city" id="3"/> Three   <br /></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="city" id="4"/> Four    <br /></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="city" id="5"/> Five    <br /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example but this example always keeps checked ones to the top, not moves the last checked one to the top.

```js
const checkboxContainer = $(".checkbox-container");

checkboxContainer.delegate("input", "change", function () {
    const checkedCheckboxes = checkboxContainer.find("input:checkbox:checked").parent();
    const uncheckedCheckboxes = checkboxContainer.find("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").parent();

    checkboxContainer.find("> *").remove();

    checkboxContainer.append(checkedCheckboxes);
    checkboxContainer.append(uncheckedCheckboxes);
});
```

```css
 .checkbox-item {
    display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox-container">
    <label class="checkbox-item">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" />
        Item 1
    </label>

    <label class="checkbox-item">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" />
        Item 2
    </label>

    <label class="checkbox-item">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" />
        Item 3
    </label>

    <label class="checkbox-item">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" />
        Item 4
    </label>

    <label class="checkbox-item">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" />
        Item 5
    </label>
</div>
```