# JQuery move items in list when checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I've been looking for some code which basically moves checkboxes to the top of a list once they have been checked.

I came accross [Move checkboxes on checked jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38841887/move-checkboxes-on-checked-jquery) which gave me a great start, but I'm now stuck on a further issue.

If I add an `<li>` item into this `<ul>` list, but its just a standard item without an `<input>` section, it stops the whole code from working.

Is there a simple work around for this that I haven't seen? I'm struggling to be honest as I'm just starting with JQuery, so its quite new to me.

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not at the end of a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code for the previous question. We can add the "typeof" to check if there's an input inside the li. This avoids the issue and remains the li static.

```js
  var list = $("ul"),
        origOrder = list.children();
    
    list.on("click", ":checkbox", function() {
        var i, checked = document.createDocumentFragment(),
            unchecked = document.createDocumentFragment();
        for (i = 0; i < origOrder.length; i++) {
            if (typeof(origOrder[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0]) != "undefined" && origOrder[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked) {
                checked.appendChild(origOrder[i]);
            } else {
                unchecked.appendChild(origOrder[i]);
            }
        }
        list.append(checked).append(unchecked);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" id="one" />One</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" id="two" />Two</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" id="three" />Three</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" id="four" />Four</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" id="five" />Five</label></li>
<li><p>Hello World!</p></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you very much, nice and efficient code.